# Sort matrix by columns and rows without changing them

Tags: matrix, sorting

I would like to sort a matrix in descending order first by the total of each column, then by the total of each row, but without changing their content. For example, if I had:

```
TableForm[{{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {Range[1, 4], Range[1, 4]}]
```

I want to sort first the columns:

```
TableForm[{{1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {Range[1, 4], {"4", "3", "1", "2"}}]
```

Then the rows:

```
TableForm[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"4", "3", "1", "2"}, {"4", "3", "1", "2"}}]
```

The goal is to get as many 1's as possible to the upper-left corner. I added `TableHeadings` to this mockup of the desired result simply to show the content of the columns/rows remains the same. If there is a better way other than using the `Total` for each column/row that is fine too. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ordering` and `Part` are applicable to this kind of problem.  `Reverse` is needed below as you want to place larger elements to the upper left rather than lower right.

```
tab = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};

tab = tab[[All, Reverse @ Ordering[tab ~Total~ {1}]]];

tab[[Reverse @ Ordering[tab ~Total~ {2}]]] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(This may not be the most efficient algorithm to achieve your goal.)

---

I believe this can also be done with one application of `Part` by computing the `Ordering` for each level beforehand:

```
newSort[x_?ArrayQ] :=
  x[[##]] & @@ (Reverse@Ordering[x ~Total~ {#}] & /@ {2, 1})

newSort[tab]
```

This could be easily extended to greater dimensions by replacing `{2, 1}` with `Range[ArrayDepth@x, 1, -1]`.

Comment: I knew about Part, but Ordering was new for me. Thanks @Mr.Wizard!

Comment: @Pancholp You're welcome.  Please see the update I just made.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Sort` :

```
Sort[Transpose[Sort[Transpose[tab], Total[#1] > Total[#2] &]], Total[#1] > Total[#2] &]
```

Comment: Thanks @b.gatessucks! This one works well too.

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.0 there is `ReverseSortBy`

```
list = {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};

ReverseSort /@ ReverseSortBy[Total] @ list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReverseSort`:

```
ReverseSort[ReverseSort /@ Transpose[tab]]

(*{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}*)
```