# Sorting a symmetric matrix alphanumerically

Tags: matrix, sorting

NOT related to my [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22202/sorting-a-matrix-alphanumerically)! (Different problem source)

This time, I want to sort a symmetric matrix M, and it must stay symmetric (i.e. row and col sort is the same). WLOG the diagonal is 0 (no relevance). This means the following restraint: Assume that M is

```
{{0, 2, 3, 6}, {2, 0, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 0, 5}, {6, 4, 5, 0}}
```

then your allowed operations are any row swap (here 2 and 3)

```
{{0, 2, 3, 6}, {3, 1, 0, 5}, {2, 0, 1, 4}, {6, 4, 5, 0}}
```

and now you must accompany it with same col swap (also 2 and 3)

```
{{0, 3, 2, 6}, {3, 0, 1, 5}, {2, 1, 0, 4}, {6, 5, 4, 0}}
```

so M is symmetric again. You are done when M is smallest by
alphanumeric comparison:

```
{{0, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 0, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 0}}
```

This of course means that the linked answer doesn't work anymore:

```
{{0, 2, 3, 6}, {2, 0, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 0, 5}, {6, 4, 5, 0}}
```

becomes a fixed point (where instead 1 shall go into the first row).

Neither does it work to just elide the diagonal, sort just by row and with the same permutation by col:

```
{{0, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 0, 1}, {4, 5, 1, 0}}
```

is correctly sorted without the 0, but not the solution.

My working algorithm is generating all possible n! M and fish out the smallest. A much better *almost* working is in the comments.

Comment: What is the correct solution in this example and what are the constraints to sorting?

Comment: How large is M likely to be and how will you know if you've reached an optimal solution?

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability: M is very small as the main problem requires to bring O(n!) M's into normal form. n=8-10 at most. The correctness must be guaranteed by the algorithm itself!...But the problem just has become moot as I read the Wiki - if an effective sorting algorithm would exist, we just would have solved the graph isomorphy problem (read M as incidency matrix) - which is in NP-intermediate.

Comment: Will your matrix contain strings?  Your title says "alphanumerically" but your example contains only numbers.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your solution.  Third row should be `{2, 3, 0, 6}`. The 2 and 3 are swapped around.

Comment: @Edmund: Correct, will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`ResourceFunction["SymmetricSort"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SymmetricSort/) and [`OrderingBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html).

With

```
MatrixForm[matrix = {{0, 2, 3, 6}, {2, 0, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 0, 5}, {6, 4, 5, 0}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
SymmetricMatrixQ[matrix]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Then symmetrically ordering by `matrix` rows

```
symMatrixNSort[m_?SymmetricMatrixQ] :=
 ResourceFunction["SymmetricSort"][m, OrderingBy[m, Total]]
```

`symMatrixNSort` symmetrically orders the rows by their total.

```
MatrixForm[res = symMatrixNSort[matrix]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SymmetricMatrixQ[res]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Your title says "alphanumerically" but your example contains only numbers so I used `Total` as the order function.  You can replace this with a function of your choice to handle your alphanumeric vectors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (+1) Your resource function `SymmetricSort` is very nice, @Edmund.

Comment: @Edmund: That's OK, in practice only numbers will show up. "Alphanumerically" for generality :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does this satisfy your constraints?

```
unsortedMatrix = {{0, 2, 3, 6}, {2, 0, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 0, 5}, {6, 4, 5, 0}};
unsortedMatrix // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{pmatrix}
>  0 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\
>  2 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
>  3 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\
>  6 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\
> \end{pmatrix}

```
unsortedVector = 
 Statistics`Library`UpperTriangularMatrixToVector[unsortedMatrix]
```

> {2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5}

```
sortedVector = Sort@unsortedVector
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

```
sortedMatrix = 
  Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[sortedVector,0,Length[unsortedMatrix]];
(* 1st argument: vector to make into matrix *)
(* 2nd argument: what to place on the diagonal *)
(* 3rd argument: n, where n-by-n is the desired matrix dimensions *)

sortedMatrix // MatrixForm
```

> \begin{pmatrix}
>  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  1 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
>  2 & 4 & 0 & 6 \\
>  3 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
> \end{pmatrix}

*Note: makes use of undocumented functions from `` Statistics`Library ``*

Comment: This is definitely correct (as a result), since the vectors stay in place, but how does it work exactly? And, even more relevant, does it work for the critical second example?

Comment: If the second example is `{{0, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 0, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 0, 1}, {4, 5, 1, 0}}` then it sorts to `{{0, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 0, 5}, {2, 4, 5, 0}}`. I will edit my answer to make the algorithm clearer

Comment: What do you mean by “the vectors stay in place”

Comment: Bad wording...The numbers of the vector stay "together". Obviously, this can't work with just sorting *all* numbers of the matrix - it's just a lucky accident that (0123),(0145),(0246) and (0356) stay together after sorting. OK, I reword it: if a matrix contains the vector (a1,a2,...) before, it must also contain this vector after sorting (in any order of the vector elements).

Comment: @HaukeReddmann it is still not clear to me what you mean by stay together. Can you edit your question to include this constraint as well as give a concrete example?

Comment: Here is an idea for an *almost* working poly-alg: 1.Sort all row vectors of mat element-wise. 2.Lump them together to a matrix mat2 and sort the cols by vector order alphanumeric. 3.Remember the permutation of step 2 (easy: patch 1...n to the end of the vectors before step 2 and extract perm afterwards). 4.Apply perm to both row and col of mat simultaneously: mat3=mat[perm[i],perm[j]]. Done. Unfortunately, with identical vectors occuring the algorithm still might fail.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help further without some examples or a definition of the vectors "staying together"

Comment: Edited. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability Your solution does not have the same eigenvalues as the starting matrix. The "staying together" means the rows can change position and the numbers in a row change position within the row. Numbers should not leave their row, only be rearranged within it.

Comment: Thanks @Edmund, I was wondering about this and I'm glad OP got a solution